# Spring Boot - how to validate fields that depend on each other?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there some way in Spring Boot that I can perform validation on properties that depend on each other's values, and have the error message be associated with the property?

I want to return the errors to the user in a nice JSON structure:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "name": "is required if flag is true"
  }
}
```

Example:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  private boolean nameRequiredFlag;

  // Required if "nameRequiredFlag" is set to true:
  private String name;
}
```

One solution **that doesn't solve my problem of associating the error message with the name property** is to create a validator annotation for the entity:

```
@ValidEntity
public class MyEntity {
  private boolean nameRequiredFlag;

  // Required if "nameRequiredFlag" is set to true:
  private String name;
}

@Constraint( validatedBy = { MyEntityValidator.class } )
@Documented
@Target( { ElementType.TYPE } )
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
public @interface ValidEntity{
  Class<?>[] groups () default {};

  String message () default "name is required if 'nameRequiredFlag' is true";

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload () default {};
}


public class MyEntityValidator implements Validator<ValidEntity, MyEntity> {
  @Override
  public boolean isValid ( MyEntity entity, ConstraintValidatorContext context ) {
    if ( !entity.nameRequiredFlag ) return true;
    
    return !StringUtils.isBlank( entity.getName() );
  }
}
```

This is laughably cumbersome and doesn't solve my problem. Isn't there any way I can do this with the framework validation?

Edit: This is for a JSON API, and the consumer really needs to be able to associate the error message to a best guess at which field has an issue. It is not helpful to send the consumer an error message for the whole object, or a computed property.

Comment: Have you tried this from the documentation : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=7.0#section-custom-property-paths ?

Comment: In isValid method you can describe field with addPropertyNode method of the context

Answer (score 9):

Solution given by @EvicKhaosKat is one way of doing it. However, when there are too many fields dependent on each other in a complicated way, your class becomes full of annotations and I personally struggle a lot relating them.

A simpler approach is to create a method(s) in your pojo which does the cross field validations and returns a boolean. On the top of this method annotate it with `@AssertTrue(message = "your message")`. It will solve your problem in a cleaner fashion.

```
public class SampleClass {

    private String duration;
    private String week;
    private String month;

    @AssertTrue(message = "Duration and time attributes are not properly populated")
    public boolean isDurationCorrect() {
        if (this.duration.equalsIgnoreCase("month")) {
            if (Arrays.asList("jan", "feb", "mar").contains(month))
                return true;
        }

        if (this.duration.equalsIgnoreCase("week")) {
            if (Arrays.asList("1-7", "8-15", "16-24", "25-31").contains(week))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: I have not tested this code but have used this approach in multiple places and it works.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this was possible, and I can probably make use of it. The issue is still that it associates the error message to the "durationCorrect" property. This is for a JSON API, and the consumer really needs to be able to associate the error message to the (best guess) field that was filled in wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this! To adapt this for Kotlin I used:
`@get:JsonIgnore @get:AssertTrue(message = "Invalid!") val isDtoValid: Boolean get() = if (isValid) true else false`

Are you aware of a way to get dynamic messages in this setup?

Comment: @Innovationchef how do i add a custom message to this? like @AssertTrue(message=myField+"is invalid")

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason is that `name` validation operates on not-yet-fully constructed object, so `nameRequiredFlag` is not filled yet.

As an option there is a `@GroupSequence` annotation, which allows to group and perform validations in an order you specify.
For example it is possible to add to `MyEntity` annotations:

```
@ValidEntity(groups = DependentValidations.class)
@GroupSequence({MyEntity.class, DependentValidations.class})
```

So all the other validation annotations on `MyEntity` class gonna be performed first, and after that `DependentValidations` group, which consists of `ValidEntity`.
Thus `ValidEntity` will be called on fully created object, and the last in order.

(`DependentValidations.class` - just an empty interface created somewhere nearby, like any other marker interface)

https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups will possibly describe that in much more details.

p.s. answer provided by @Innovationchef will possibly suit the case more :)

Comment: I can safely assume that all fields have been filled! Thank you though! I think the other developers would kill me if I did something that annotation-based. We want straightforward procedural code as much as possible.